# How to handle unrelated input such as letters on a trained deep learning MNIST dataset

Tags: classification, deep-learning

The MNIST dataset (usually trained with CNN)  aims to recognize the following numbers {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}. So it is trained under the assumption that the input should be a number between 0 to 9.

Thus by default there is 10 classes. This means that even if someone gives a totally unrelated input such as a picture containing an animal, a handwritten Chinese character or even a Latin handwritten letter from a-z the model will 'believe' that it is a number between 0 and 9 and will output the number with the highest probability score.

So my question is how to make the model predict a 'unrelated' class?

Should I create an extra 11th 'unrelated' class before to train my model? If yes how should I do. I can't imagine using all the existing pictures and handwritten symbols different than {0,...,9}... That sounds completely infeasible...

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it is definitely infeasible. But, you don't want to provide all different types of images there. You need just enough so the model can learn that anything unrelated should be classified there. But beware, if you include only color images in the so called "random class", there is a huge chance for the model to learn that  any color image is classified as "random class", and any black and white image is classified as 0-9. Because of that, you want to provide a variety of different images belonging to different categories, some even random letters written in the same format as the 0-9.